# Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding, when trying to start uwsgi

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, uwsgi

I am trying to start my uwsgi server in my virtual environment, but after I added `plugin python3` option I get this error every time:

```
!!! Python Home is not a directory: /home/env3/educ !!!
Set PythonHome to /home/env3/educ
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/env3/educ'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/home/env3/educ/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/home/env3/educ/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/env3/educ'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/env3/educ'
  sys.executable = '/home/env3/educ/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/home/env3/educ'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/env3/educ'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/env3/educ/lib/python38.zip',
    '/home/env3/educ/lib/python3.8',
    '/home/env3/educ/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007efe89db8780 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Also I tried to create new virtual environment using `python3 -m venv env` and moved project files to it, but still the same error.
Here is my uwsgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]

base = /home/env3/educ
projectname = educ

plugins = python3
master = true
virtualenv = /home/env3/%(projectname)
pythonpath = %(base)
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%(projectname).settings.pro
module = %(projectname).wsgi:application
socket = /tmp/%(projectname).sock
chmod-socket = 666
```

I use Python 3.8.5

I am trying to use Django + uWSGI + nginx + Postgresql.

Comment: I'm also having that random error while starting up  python. No idea why this occurs

Comment: Having this same issue on WSL2, and it's particularly crippling because I can't even use `apt` without getting this: `Reading package lists... Done E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi' E: Sub-process returned an error code`. 
Incredibly frustrating, and unfortunately unset didn't work in my case.

Comment: See also https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/issues/64#issuecomment-1537221491

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I see your PYTHONHOME is set to `PYTHONHOME = '/home/env3/educ'`. Try to check if it is really there.

**The solution** for me was to **remove the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable**.
For you, it can be just that, or setting that variable to another value.
This worked on Windows, and would work on Linux for sure. If someone tries this on Linux, please post a comment here !

A CPython developer confirmed the solution [here.](https://discuss.python.org/t/fatal-python-error-init-fs-encoding-failed-to-get-the-python-codec-of-the-filesystem-encoding/3173) :

> This is not a Python bug, this is a symptom of setting PYTHONHOME and/or PYTHONPATH when they’re not needed. **In nearly all cases you don’t need to set either of them**;
>
> In the case of PYTHONHOME **it’s almost always a mistake to set**.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but for me the home and path are already not set. any ideas?

Comment: ok so i deleted python from my pc and then reinstalled it and its working again, although I do have to reinstall all my pip libraries now

Answer (score 13):

I solve this problem by unsetting PYTHONHOME or PYTHONPATH, because they override the virtual environment variables.

**In my case** this is caused by my admin's base environment. I would try removing PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH variables by doing

```
unset PYTHONPATH
unset PYTHONHOME
```

Comment: Where do you put this? In the terminal or in the file that you are trying to run?

Comment: In the terminal, it unsets the PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME, "unset" is a terminal command

Comment: What commands to use in Windows

Comment: for windows you can set PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME to empty strings using, "set PYTHONPATH=
set PYTHONHOME="

Comment: This worked for me so if anyone else comes across this on Linux then try this before looking elsewhere

Answer (score 7):

This message is for those with the same problem who will find this page later.
I couldn't start uWSGI with my config, and I had the same message in logging files.

> init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem
> encoding Python runtime state: core initialized ModuleNotFoundError:
> No module named 'encodings'

The problem was uWSGI didn't have enough permissions to access the virtual environment. When I fixed the permissions, uWSGI started my config.

Denys posted the uwsgi.ini config in his message. I guess the path to the virtual environment is wrong.

```
base = /home/env3/educ
projectname = educ
virtualenv = /home/env3/%(projectname)
```

If the virtual environment was created in the project directory, then the path should look like this:

```
virtualenv = /home/env3/%(projectname)/env
```

Comment: In my case, I added a `/bin` at the end of the virtualenv path, and that is what was causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the problem in my case was in the setting of virtualenv. Under linux system, the path to virtualenv starts very likely as /home/(your login username)/env3/, not /home/env3/. So before you try other solutions, you had better make sure the path to your virtualenv is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the environment variable `PYTHONHOME`

### Solution

Just before the line where this error occurs, add the following

```
import os
if 'PYTHONHOME' in os.environ:
   del os.environ['PYTHONHOME']
```

### Explanation

I encountered this issue when [attempting to execute](https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/blob/c47d2368a5a85819b04549f5355f51df45c82042/src/packages/buskill/__init__.py#L1109-L1118) `cinnamon-screensaver-command --lock` using the `subprocess` module inside a python app running as an AppImage (which extracts and executes itself in a temporary squashfs filesystem).

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/tmp/.mount_buskilParXTg/opt/python3.7'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/tmp/.mount_buskilParXTg/opt/python3.7'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/tmp/.mount_buskilParXTg/opt/python3.7'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/tmp/.mount_buskilParXTg/opt/python3.7'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/tmp/.mount_buskilParXTg/opt/python3.7'
  sys.path = [
    '/tmp/.mount_buskilParXTg/opt/python3.7/lib/python38.zip',
    '/tmp/.mount_buskilParXTg/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.8',
    '/tmp/.mount_buskilParXTg/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

If you unset the environment variable (with `del os.environ['PYTHONHOME']`), then [the issue](https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/issues/64) goes away.

Comment: What do you mean by the line where the error occurs? I don't even use the `encodings` module but this issue is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to remove `home=` variable and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using **http=127.0.0.1:8000** in uwsgi.ini file.
that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I did not unset the pythonhome, pythonpath
Just simply type this in cygwin terminal:

python.exe setup.py install   (take note of the ".exe")