# Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding Python runtime state: core initialized ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, django

No matter what I do I can't fix the problem. I'm having trouble deploying. I am getting error 503 Service Unavailable.

```
Current thread 0x00007f6008afd740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/usr/virtualenv/core/3.8'
  PYTHONPATH = '.:/home/usr/core/'
  program name = '/home/usr/virtualenv/core/3.9/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/home/usr/virtualenv/core/3.9/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/usr/virtualenv/core/3.8'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/usr/virtualenv/core/3.8'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib64'
  sys.executable = '/home/usr/virtualenv/core/3.9/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/home/usr/virtualenv/core/3.8'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/usr/virtualenv/core/3.8'
  sys.path = [
    '.',
    '/home/usr/core/',
    '/home/usr/virtualenv/core/3.8/lib64/python39.zip',
    '/home/usr/virtualenv/core/3.8/lib64/python3.9',
    '/home/usr/virtualenv/core/3.8/lib64/python3.9/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fdbc7fe0740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

I tried almost all the methods I came across with the Google search engine, i tried [removing the PYTHONHOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65740883/14225304), which is the most popular solution. I also tried with Linux and Windows. But I never understood the problem. I would be very happy if someone could help me with this.