# Encountering Fatal Python error when I try to use pip in command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am a new programmer who is trying to follow [this tutorial about pip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9z7gGUbAj5U).

In the tutorial, you are asked to go into command prompt and type 'pip'. You are supposed to get a list of general options and commands. However, when I type pip in my command prompt, I get this instead:

```
C:\Users\myusername>pip
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007590 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

(I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.10.4)

I do not know what this means. This is not addressed in the video. This happens whenever I do anything pip-related in the command prompt. I am going to reference this error a lot, so let's call it "The Error."

Here is how I have tried to resolve this problem:

1. Running command prompt as administrator. When I type "pip", this returns The Error.
2. Downloading [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), trying to install it via command prompt with `python get-pip.py`. This returns The Error.
3. Updating my version of Python. I updated the version of Python I have when I encountered this error, making sure that the "Install pip" and "add Python to environment variables" checkboxes were ticked. Updating Python did not fix the problem.
4. executing `py -3 -m ensurepip` and `py -m ensurepip --upgrade` in the command prompt. This returns The Error.
5. Checking that pip is installed in the Scripts folder in Python. It is:

[Click here to see my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLNbo.png)

6. in command prompt, changing the directory to `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts` and trying `pip --version` and `pip install camelcase` from there. This returns The Error. (camelcase is not part of my project, I tried it purely as an example.)
7. Trying a non-pip related Python command in the command prompt. `python --version` returns `Python 3.10.4`, this works as expected.
8. Following [this Stack Overflow post from someone experiencing the same error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65184937/fatal-python-error-init-fs-encoding-failed-to-get-the-python-codec-of-the-file). This is beyond my understanding, and appears to be about Django. I am not doing anything with Django. I just want to use pip. The one piece of information I gleaned from this is this quote from a python developer:

> 

```
This is not a Python bug, this is a symptom of setting PYTHONHOME and/or PYTHONPATH when they’re not needed. In nearly all cases you don’t need to set either of them;

In the case of PYTHONHOME it’s almost always a mistake to set.
```

This does not apply to my case, because my PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH are not set. The commands `unset PYTHONPATH` and `unset PYTHONHOME` return `'unset' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I have no idea what's going on and I am confused. All I want to do is go into the command prompt, type `pip` and see the list of commands that is supposed to come up. I also want to be able to install python modules using pip. These seem like basic things that should automatically work, yet for some reason I am encountering a problem that is out of my depth.

I am not trying to do anything fancy. I am a basic user who has been learning basic Python for less than a month, with no prior coding experience. How can I overcome this error so I can successfully use pip? Please keep my level of understanding in mind when you answer my question. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I am trying to run some code in PyCharm and I am getting an error that says "failed to create virtual environment."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to uninstall and reinstall python, this time telling it to set environment variables. That did the trick.