# go python build issue

Tags: python, go

go path building issue and facing problems with it.

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/usr/local'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000000200919600 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
go: error obtaining buildID for go tool link: exit status 1
```

tried running go but facing python build issue

these are logs which I get after running golang.

Comment: Do the solutions in either of these fix things for you? [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65184937/fatal-python-error-init-fs-encoding-failed-to-get-the-python-codec-of-the-file), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings).

Comment: Please read [ask]. I think your title can be improved.